# What software can I use to co-ordinate a projector screen?

Tags: windows-7, projector

When I connect my laptop to a projector, it shows everything that is going-on on my computer. However, I want want to show only certain things to users ( like videos, images, etc ). It would be good if my mouse-motions could be hidden as well.

So is there any software using which I can give presentations without sharing my screen with the projector ( that is, it shows what I want it to show rather than mirroring what's going on in my laptop screen ) ?I've serached Google a lot and haven't found a solution as yet.

Update : 
I am using Windows 7 Ultimate Edition.

Update :
Laptop model: HP Probook 4410s

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Have you tried looking at the display options?

Comment: More info such as what has been asked for above  and the make/model of the laptop will help.  Video card maker as well.

Comment: Does it have Intel graphics or discrete graphics?

Answer (score 1):

Most laptops allow you to display the presentation on the external monitor/projector and show whatever on the laptop screen  Most are managed by a tool provided by the graphic card maker (nVida for example).  Check the control panel for an app from the video maker.  There is usually a wizard to walk through setup.  NVIDIA nView Desktop manager is one common one.  ATI Hydra Vision is another.  Also ATI catalyst control center

In other cases the laptop manufacturer has a utility to do this.

Windows Display Manager has some fuctionality as well.

Comment: Examples are...?

Comment: I can't find Windows Display Manager anywhere. Where can I find it?

Comment: Given your using windows 7 try pressing 'Win' +P which if the drivers are set up correctly will give you the output options.  Tap 'p' until 'extend' is selected, this will put you into dual head mode, in which the output screen shows something different to the internal one